# Cost of hosting php and asp.net web api

Tags: c#, php, asp.net

We are a small startup with majority PHP talent and also C# talent. We're working on a web service which is going to we be talking to multiple clients like our website, phone apps and some embedded devices. We have decided to go with asp.net Web API for the web service and php for the web site.

Being a startup we are extremely sensitive to cost. Is this setup too costly to host and what would the performance be like if we host this configuration on a single server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Visit [Azure pricing tab](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/websites/). Your best bet is to host WebAPI on Azure or a Windows VPS.

In case of VPS, you can buy managed windows VPS (costly) or an un-managed windows VPS. A quick Google search can give you the cost estimates for same.

In case of Azure Websites, everything is managed by MS & you just need to deploy your code to Azure.

If you can't afford Azure, go with PHP for REST services.

In general, hosting on Linux is much cheaper than windows.

Apart from hosting, you may need to invest in SQL server (you can also use MySQL on windows). VS 2013 community is now free and hence you have saved some cost for IDE.

Assuming you choose windows, performance depends on so many things (server config, code etc). No can answer this vague question.  Having said that, IIS can handle large volumes.

Comment: Thanks. Our original plan was to host the website and the web service on different servers. Now in order to save cost we are thinking of hosting both on the same windows server. Is this setup good? If not can you tell me why specifically. Especially in terms of overhead

Comment: First you need to decide if you want to go with Windows Azure (Azure VM or Azure Website) or traditional Windows VPS. It is OK to host both on same website as long as your server is good enough to handle the load. As long as your hardware is good, you wont have any issue.